# In the timeline, should the start of a bounty by the OP also be considered a change to the question by the OP?

Tags: support, bug, design, timeline

I noticed that if the OP of a question makes an edit to their question or comments under their question, then in the corresponding event in the timeline the OP's username is highlighted by a grey box around to it, presumably to distinguish it from events caused by users other than the OP. ([A random example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/337237/timeline).)

However, if the OP starts a bounty on their question, then their username is not highlighted. I noticed this on the [timeline to a question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/posts/10572/timeline) on Music Fans SE, but I presume this is the case everywhere:

> [image: timeline screenshot]

Is there any reason why bounties started by the OP do not have a highlighted entry for the OP's username in the "BY" column in the timeline? I've tagged this as [support](/questions/tagged/support) as well as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), because I'm not sure whether this is an oversight or is as intended.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: no, I don't think the name of the OP should be highlighted for bounty events.

---

The highlight background for the post author is meant only for comments: it let us easily see who is the OP in a long comments thread.

The fact it was "imported" to the time line is a nice bonus, but it should be limited to comments, to make it persistent.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more accurate to say "is meant only for comments *and edits*"? On a side note, this is the first time I have seen the use of TL;DR on a post with only two other sentences :)

Comment: I also don't understand what "it" is when you say "to make it persistent". What exactly is persisting here?

Comment: @Brahadeesh no, when OP edits own post, there's no special background color, it just says "edited 2 hours ago", for example. So the different background for OP edit is also a bonus feature of the time line page. In "make it persistent" I mean persistent with the post view itself.

Comment: I don't follow. I am not talking about the "edited 2 hours ago" on my post, but on the [timeline event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/348371/timeline) against "2 hours ago", where my username is indeed highlighted. Your brevity is not helpful - make *what* persistent with the post view?