# OP name not highlighted in reopen action in timeline

Tags: bug, design, timeline, original-poster

As far as I know OP name should always be highlighted, but for some reason doesn't for reopen action in timeline, [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/364350/timeline):

> [image: no highlighting for OP]

Comment: Related: "[In the timeline, should the start of a bounty by the OP also be considered a change to the question by the OP?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348371)" with an answer stating: "[...] The highlight background for the post author is meant only for comments [...]"